# External links are not working in ibooks

Tags: ipad, epub, ibooks

Is there any way to add external link as an item in opf file? Or is it possible to embed external web page in ibooks? I tried to add

<item id="extlink" href="http://example.com/link.html" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" properties="online-resource"/>

as an item in opf file and i am getting "resource missing" error in ipad. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

All the assets of an EPUB must be contained inside the EPUB container.

The only exceptions are for audio/video files (see e.g. http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2013/05/linking-to-external-video-and-audio-in.html )

Also note that the correct property is `remote-resources`, not `online-resource` (see http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications-20110523.html#sec-resource-locations )

You can still add links to the XHTML pages inside the EPUB, pointing to your external page. If clicked, the system browser will be triggered and it will load them (if an Internet connection is available).